# How can I autofill an input value getting a specific column from a rails 4 association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to rails 4 and I would like to know if it is possible to fill a field value in my form with an existing column from other table.

I was thinking in using JQuery for doing it automatically, but somehow I can't figure it out.

My Models have this relationships:

**ordem_de_servico.rb**

> `belongs_to :cliente 
>   belongs_to :mecanico 
>   belongs_to :servico`

**cliente.rb**

> `has_many :ordem_de_servicos, dependent: :destroy
>   has_many :mecanicos, through: :ordem_de_servicos
>   has_many :servicos, through: :ordem_de_servicos`

**mecanico.rb**

> `has_many :ordem_de_servicos, dependent: :destroy
>   has_many :clientes, through: :ordem_de_servicos
>   has_many :servicos, through: :ordem_de_servicos`

**servico.rb**

> `has_many :ordem_de_servicos, dependent: :destroy
>    has_many :clientes, through: :ordem_de_servicos
>    has_many :mecanicos, through: :ordem_de_servicos`

**my Ordem_de_serviço _form.html.erb is:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :cliente, :class => "control-label col-xs-2 required" %>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
    <%= f.select :cliente_id, options_for_select(Cliente.all.map{ |s| [s.nome, s.id] }), :class => "form-control" %>
   </div>
     <%= error_span(@ordem_de_servico[:cliente]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :serviço, :class => "control-label col-xs-2 required" %>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
    <%= f.select :servico_id, options_for_select(Servico.all.map{ |s| [s.nome, s.id] }) %>
   </div>
    <%= error_span(@ordem_de_servico[:servico_id]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :mecânico, :class => "control-label col-xs-2 required" %>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
    <%= f.select :mecanico_id, options_for_select(Mecanico.all.map{ |s| [s.nome, s.id] }) %>
   </div>
    <%= error_span(@ordem_de_servico[:mecanico_id]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2 required">Valor M. Obra</label>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
    <%= f.text_field :valor_obra, :class => "form-control", :style => "width: auto;" %>
   </div>
    <%= error_span(@ordem_de_servico[:valor_obra]) %>
  </div>
```

**The thing is I want to automatically fill the field "valor_obra" with the column "valor" from Servicos table when you select the field servico_id.**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally untested.

[options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) allows you to specify an optional third value that is a hash of html attributes.  So you could change your servicio code to something like:

```
<%= f.select :servico_id, options_for_select(Servico.all.map{ |s| [s.nome, s.id, {data: {valor: s.valor}}] }), id: 'servicio-select' %>
```

This *should* give your a `data-valor` attribute on each `<option>` tag.  Note that I also gave the `<select>` tag an id of `servicio-select` so we can target it with jquery.  Let's also give the valor_obra input an id so we can target it also:

```
<%= f.text_field :valor_obra, :class => "form-control", :style => "width: auto;", :id => 'valor-obra-input' %>
```

Now we can throw in a little jquery magic to do the rest for us:

```
$('#servicio-select').change(function() {
  $('#valor-obra-input').val($('#servicio-select:selected').data('valor'));
}):
```

That should update the value of `#valor-obra-input` with the value of the attribute `data-valor` of the selected option of `#servicio-select`.

Comment: Formerly, I would like to say thanks, even though I couldn't solve the problem, you really understood the idea. If you would like to help me a litle bit, I wasn't able to set {data: {valor: s.valor}, because there are two arguments for one, the only thing that I did was changing to {valor: s.valor}, the hash loaded the columns properly, but I couldn't call the value in Jquery. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm... changing from `{data: {valor: s.valor}}` to `{valor: s.valor}` doesn't seem like it should change the number of arguments being passed to anything.  You could try `{'data-valor' => s.valor}` or `{:'data-valor' => s.valor}`, both of which should create the same `data-valor` attribute, albeit less elegantly.  Alternatively, if you are successfully creating a `valor` attribute, you could change the jquery from `$('#servicio-select:selected').data('valor')` to `$('#servicio-select:selected').attr('valor')` to use the `valor` attribute instead.

Comment: It worked with {'data-valor' => s.valor}, as you said, it is not the most elegant code but it works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can accomplish this, I would argue the simplest approach is to set the value of that field in the controller before the view is rendered, like so:

```
def new
    # ... other code
    @ordem_de_servico.valor_obra = some_value
end
```

Where `some_value` is the value from the other table you wish to set.

The reason why this works is the same reason why your fields are populated when you "edit" an object; your `f.text_field` fields populate the form based on the name you specify. Therefore, if you set a value on a field of your model object, it'll be "automatically" populated when the form is rendered.

*Note: I am making an assumption on the name of your object, but I'm sure you get the idea if the name is incorrect*